# titanuum mobile xmlmarkup events

Tags: templates, events, mobile, titanium

moving from actionscript (flex) to titanium and I'm experimenting with the xml markup. What I have is a template that I picked up from the doc

```
<ItemTemplate name="template">
                    <ImageView left="0" bindId="pic" id="icon" />
                    <Label bindId="info" id="title"/>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </Templates>
```

my question is if someone clicks on the pic or a listitem itself, how does one handle the events. through xml markup? Then how do you reference any of the control wrap in the template?

I have tried

```
<ImageView left="0" bindId="pic" id="icon" onclick="doClick()" />


function doClick(e) {

    alert($.info.text);
}
```

This just produces a error and I still would not know what pic was clicked.

any help would be great..

thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Alloy Quick Start](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start)? I think many of your questions can be answered there.

Anyway, for ListViews, you cant add an event listener to an item in the template, its just a template not an actual thing on the screen (yet), [refer here, and look at the alloy section.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView)

Instead you need the `itemclick` event listener on the ListView itself. Check , below for a simple example of what the XML markup looks like.

```
    <ListView id="listView" defaultItemTemplate="template" onitemclick="yourEvent" >

        <!-- The Templates tag sets the ListView's templates property -->

        <Templates>

            <!-- Define your item templates within the Templates tags or use the
            Require tag to include a view that only contains an ItemTemplate -->

            <ItemTemplate name="template">
                <ImageView bindId="pic" id="icon" />
                <Label bindId="info" id="title" />
                <Label bindId="es_info" id="subtitle" />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </Templates>
        <ListSection headerTitle="Fruit / Frutas">

            <!-- You can specify any ListItem or ListDataItem properties in ListItem -->

            <!-- Specify data to bind to the item template with inline attributes
            defined as <bindId>:<Ti.UI.Component.property> -->

            <ListItem info:text="Apple" es_info:text="Manzana" pic:image="/apple.png" />
            <ListItem info:text="Banana" es_info:text="Banana" pic:image="/banana.png" />
        </ListSection>
    </ListView>
```

Also, you need any JavaScript to be in the controller files, not in the XML markup files. *.js has javascript that is behind the view, which is *.xml.

Comment: Hi Josiah,yes the javascarip is in its controller, I did go through the docs but it didn't cover some some items (this begin one) I'll give this a try but I still will need to figure out what listItem got click and how to reference the contols in that ListItem. thanks again

Comment: The `itemClick` event passes the section, and number of the item clicked, [check it out here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView-event-itemclick)!